# "Cannot find name 'serviceworkerregistration'" when using firebase >= 5.0.1 in cloud functions

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have some shared typescript code between my Ionic app and cloud functions in a separate nodejs package which includes some models, utils, ... Now, I also use some classes of firebase firestore in it like GeoPoint and Timestamp. When I use firebase package 5.0.1 or above I got an exception like "cannot find name 'serviceworkerregistration'" when I want to build my cloud functions project.
Any idea on whats the best way to deal with some shared code which includes firestore logic?

Answer (score 0):

While they may look similar, the Cloud Firestore API is slightly different between the web client SDK and the server SDK.

You need to be using the client SDK in the app, and the server SDK on Cloud Functions.  They cannot be interchanged.

On top of that, since they have different types for everything, you will have a hard time trying to write a common interface that you can invoke from either the app or the function.  If you really want to create a common library that either one can use, you will effectively have to make a common class that delegates to either the client SDK or the server SDK depending on the runtime environment.